# how to execute a command as root in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins for a job and I want to execute a command as root in execute shell but when I run 
sudo su  and then whoami I get the result ubuntu. Is there anyway I could run the command as root user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already added Jenkins in `sudo` user group, if not then add this `jenkins        ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL` or

[Is it possible to allow jenkins to access the files that only root or some specific programs have access to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096784/is-it-possible-to-allow-jenkins-to-access-the-files-that-only-root-or-some-speci)

`sudo su` will not work because Jenkins run the command as a script, you have to option

- inline sudo user command
- create script and then run with `sudo user`

`sudo su - root -c 'whoami'`

[image]
[image]

or save your command to bash script, then run with `sudo`.

`sudo /path_to_command.sh`

Comment: yes can pass the number of command like `sudo su - root -c 'cd /stream/sources/wowza-module; pwd; git stash; git fetch && git checkout branch; git pull; git stash pop; ant;mv build/stream.jar /usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/lib/'`